# ExpressionTree rewrite - The parameter 'x' is not in scope

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda, expression-trees

*If I make any mistakes/mistypes in the following code, please don't get irrate, just drop a comment on here and I'll fix immediately - thanks*

#### Goal

Re-map `Expression<TDelegate>` from one `EntityA` to a `EntityB`.

I suspect this kind of thing has been done before but I haven't found any particularly useful links so feel free to point me in the right direction.

What I have so far is a selection of classes that combine to allow for mappings to be created between Entity Members on two given classes.  As an example, the surface API might have the following signature:

```
public void AddMemberBinding<TEntityA, TEntityB, TMember>(Func<TEntityA, TMember> entityAMemberSelector, Func<TEntityB, TMember> entityBMemberSelector)
{
    // does some magic, eventually storing the necessary MemberInfo details required to
    // "remap" MemberExpressions (MemberAccess) from TEntityA to TEntityB
}
```

Given the following classes...

```
public class EntityA
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set ;}
}
public class EntityB
{
    public long MyId { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

You would be able to create bindings with something along the lines of...

```
public static void AddBindings()
{
    AddMemberBinding((EntityA n) => n.Id, (EntityB n) => n.MyId);
    AddMemberBinding((EntityA n) => n.Name, (EntityB n) => n.MyName);
}
```

In my case, I have `Assembly1` that knows what `EntityA` is, but does not know `EntityB`.  I have `Assembly2` which knows what both `EntityA` and `EntityB` are, and is visible to `Assembly1`.  `Assembly2` provides a method to `Assembly1` which might look as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<EntityA> GetData<TResult>(Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>> criteria, Expression<Func<EntityA, TResult>> selector)
{
    // EntityB's are stored in a database, I could do one of two things here...
    // 1) Return all EntitieB's and then apply criteria and selector through the IEnumerable extensions
    //    this would be sub-optimal - particularly if there are millions of EntityB's!
    // 2) "Transmute" (for lack of a better word) the expressions provided, using the keymappings
    //    specified earlier, to derive expressions that can be passed through to the QueryableProvider
    // ... as you might have guessed, I opted for #2
}
```

I'm using a derived version of the [ExpressionTree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=VS.90).aspx), with the following overridden methods:

```
protected override Expression VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
{
    Type targetParameterType = lambda.Parameters[0].Type;
    Type targetExpressionType = lambda.Type;
    If (lambda.Parameters.Count = 1 && lambda.Parameters(0).Type == EntityA)
    {
        targetParameterType = EntityB;
        // the `GetResultType` method called gets the TResult type from Func<T, TResult>
        Type targetExpressionResultType = GetResultType(lambda);
        targetExpressionType = gettype(Func<EntityB, targetExpressionResultType>) 
    }
    // this is probably wrong, but maintains the current (last) parameter instance
    // I started doing this after reading about a similar issue to mine found:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411738/expression-or-the-parameter-item-is-not-in-scope
    this.CurrentLambdaParameters = lambda.Parameters.Select(x => Expression.Parameter(targetParameterType, x.Name));
    Expression body = this.Visit(lambda.Body);
    If (body != lambda.Body)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda(targetExpressionType, body, this.CurrentLambdaParameters);
    }
    return lambda;
}

protected override Expression VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m)
{
    // at this point I go off and look at key mappings, fetch the mapping required, etc
    // the entity I retrieve has a `TargetMemberInfo` property which is a `MemberInfo` for the
    // member on the target entity - speaks for itself I guess...
    return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(this.CurrentParameters.Single(), myMappingClassThing.TargetMemberInfo);
}
```

#### The Problem

With all that said and done, when I run through the code with a test case, I get the error in the title... I can see it's a parameter issue from the description, but having read about [a similiar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411738/expression-or-the-parameter-item-is-not-in-scope) I had hoped I had accounted for the problem in the `VisitMemberAccess` method by using the parameter I created when modifying the root lambda expression - same instance of ParameterExpression fixed the linked questions problem I think?

It seems I didn't understand that part of the process very well.  The question is, where did I go wrong!?  What is it I need to do with these ParameterExpressions for them to be ""in scope""?

Thanks in advance for your answers, and if you read this far, kudos to you!!

Comment: This reminds me of a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797261/mutating-the-expression-tree-of-a-predicate-to-target-another-type) I had in the past. See if that one helps you. Note: the end result was much more complex to automatically account for several cases, but the core idea is the same.

Comment: That looks perfect Jon.  I'll let you know how I get on shortly.  I just wish your question came up in the search when I started mine!!

Comment: @Jon - it turns out the answer for me was MUCH simpler. My overridden method `VisitMemberAccess` was not continuing the recursion, instead treating MemberAccess as a leaf. =/  Probably not obvious in my question due to the code omittions.  Your question/answer was very useful though, refactoring to use some of your better practices lead me straight to it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst looking over [Jon's remarkably similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797261/mutating-the-expression-tree-of-a-predicate-to-target-another-type) and refactoring to incorporate a couple of his practices I preferred to my own implementation, I stumbled across the answer.  I noticed that `VisitParameter` was never called, the reason for which is that my override of `VisitMemberAccess` discontinued the recursion through the expression tree.

It should have looked like (using a different overload):

```
protected override Expression VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m) 
{ 
    return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Visit(m.Expression), myMappingClassThing.TargetMemberInfo); 
}
```

Combine that with ensuring you don't create multiple instances of the same parameter and everything slots together nicely.

Thanks again to Jon! =)