# ExpressionTree rewrite - MakeMemberAccess() for Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, expression-trees

*Related vaguely to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332488/expressiontree-rewrite-the-parameter-x-is-not-in-scope)*

***Note** : I'm using a derivative of the ExpressionTree visitor as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)*

In my `VisitMemberAccess` method I currently create MemberExpressions using something along the lines of:

```
// `mapping` is a class used to map EntityA's members to EntityB's members
return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Visit(m.Expression), mapping.TargetMemberInfo);
```

For the most part, this works.

Given some test classes...

```
public class EntityA
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public long MyId {get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

The code will correctly map `(EntityA x) => x.Id` to `(EntityB x) => x.MyId` which is great and works lovely.  My problem comes when you introduce navigation properties:

```
public class EntityB
{
    public long MyId {get; set; }
    public EntityBDetails NavigationProperty { get; set; }
}    

public class EntityBDetails
{
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

Given the above trivial case, I would want `(EntityA x) x => x.Name` to map to `(EntityB x) x => x.NavigationProperty.Name`.  And therelies the problem, I have no idea what to supply to `MakeMemberAccess` to make this work...  I can compare `mapping.TargetMemberInfo.DeclaringType == mapping.TargetMemberInfo.ReflectedType` to determine whether there is a navigation property involved, but how do I create the necessary MemberExpression?

Thanks in advance!

*NB: The code base I'm working on is VB; C# tends to get better/faster answers on SO so I've converted by hand.  Let me know if I've made silly typo's/etc*

Comment: I've just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gener) - the [answer by Davy Landman](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gener/308863#308863) looks like it contains what I need - need to go away and factor it in.  Will update.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it could help to translate the C# code into English, and then translate that into an expression-creating code:

The expression `x.NavigationProperty.Name` actually means “access property `NavigationProperty` on `x` and then access property `Name` on the result. Now, the code:

```
ParameterExpression x = …;
var navigationProperty = typeof(EntityB).GetProperty("NavigationProperty");
var name = typeof(EntityBDetails).GetProperty("Name");

var navigationPropertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(x, navigationProperty);
var nameAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(navigationPropertyAccess , name);
```

Comment: -1 I'm all for constructive critiscm and being corrected but `"I think it could help to translate the C# code into English"` seems a little more like mocking to me... perhaps I've misread your statement?  The reason I called it "Navigation Property" is because that is what it is referred to in [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx) which is the ORM I'm using...

Comment: I didn't mean it as mocking. It looked like you didn't get the point that you have to use `MakeMemberAccess()` twice, since you have two property accesses in the expression you want to create. I know you know what the expression does. But I think it can be useful to stop and think what it actually means, by translating the C# into English. And I didn't comment about the naming, so I'm not sure why you mentioned it.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't realised I needed to call `MakeMemberExpression` multiple times until I read the answer on the question I linked in the comments above.  I think I understand the context of the aforementioned statement now.  Feel free to make a minor edit and I'll remove the -1.  Thanks for the answer