# Serialize an expression with an variable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I wrote some classes to serialize `System.Linq.Expressions` to DataContracts to be able to send via WCF. It works quite good nice. the problem is when i want to serialize an expression that has a variable in it. here is an example to explain the problem:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// CASE 1
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> lambda = foo => foo.Name == "Test";
Console.WriteLine(lambda);
// OUTPUT: foo => (foo.Name == "Test")

// CASE 2
var variable = "Test";
lambda = foo => foo.Name == variable;            
this.AssertExpression(lambda, "Class Lambda expression with variable.");
// OUTPUT: foo => (foo.Name == value(MyTest+<>c__DisplayClass0).variable)
```

i am not having trouble to serialize the CASE 2 expression, but the the data i serialize is useless, since on the service side, there is nothing to resolve `value(MyTest+<>c__DisplayClass0).variable`

so i need to resolve the variables before i serialize that expression so that the CASE 2 expression serializes to same result as CASE1

Comment: I had a similiar issue expression walking for a totally different reason.  Long story short, when walking the tree check for Member access, if the member is not TSource of your expression, drill down to the value within the member and place it within a Constant instead.  Don't have time right now to expand on this, but hopefully put you on the right track.  Let me know if you need me to expand and I'll do a proper answer... GL!  EDIT: I asked a question on this so you may find reference code if you have a scan voer them - for some reason I believe they are ranked -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Sorry for the VB, but</strike> the following extract is the bit of code I meant in my comment.  I don't think it covers all the bases <strike>(i.e. it may not be drilling down far enough so make sure you test it)</strike> but for <strike>simple</strike> most examples it works:

The code is based on [this MSDN Expression Visitor example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
class CustomExpressionWalker<TSource> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m)
    {
        if (m.Member.DeclaringType != typeof(TSource))
        {
            // We are accessing a member/variable on a class
            // We need to descend the tree through the navigation properties and eventually derive a constant expression
            return this.VisitMemberAccess(m, m.Type);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected Expression VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m, Type expectedType)
    {
        if (m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        {
            // We are at the end of the member expression 
            // i.e. MyClass.Something.Something.Value <-- we're at the Value part now
            ConstantExpression constant = (ConstantExpression)m.Expression;
            return Expression.Constant(m.Expression.Type.GetFields().Single(n => n.FieldType == expectedType && m.Member.Name.Contains(n.Name)).GetValue(constant.Value));
        }
        else if (m.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(TSource))
        {
            // I'm unsure of your current implementation but the original Member access
            // regarding serializing the expression, but if the code reaches here a nested
            // MemberAccess has landed on a Property/variable of type TSource, so you'll need
            // to decide whether to serialize here or not.  For example, if TSource was of 
            // type "myClass", it could be 
            // (myOtherClass x) => x.myClass
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        else if (m.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(Nullable))
        {
            // never got round to implementing this as we don't need it yet
            // if you want to deal with Nullable<T> you're going to have to 
            // examine the logic here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        else
        {
            // continue walking the member access until we derive the constant
            return this.VisitMemberAccess((MemberExpression)m.Expression, expectedType);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: [The original issue I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334668/expressiontree-rewrite-makememberaccess-for-navigation-properties) was that I didn't continue walking the tree when the MemberAccess was a non `TSource` class, the above logic should actually recursively root those cases out so ignore my original comment.  I've left in the `Nullable<T>` clause *(on the* `else if`*)* statement as I don't think the existing logic will cover those cases, it may also struggle with Generic classes.

That said, this should put you in good stead.  If you're not using the Expression Visitor, can you provide some more details/code?

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, that pretty much nailed it after i removed the `n.FieldType == expectedType`.